# Active class stays activated and I need that this activate class do not stays active when I scroll

Tags: javascript

this are the global variables

```
const navigation = document.getElementById('nav_list');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const links = document.querySelectorAll('li')
let navLinks = '';
```

this function was use to create the nav.

```
const navMaker = function() {

    sections.forEach(section => {
                const sectId = section.id;
                const sectNav = section.dataset.name;
                navLinks = navLinks + `<li><a class="links_menu" href="#${sectId}">${sectNav}</a> 
                </li>`;
    });
    navigation.innerHTML = navLinks; 
}

 navMaker();
```

This functions were use to to add and remove the active class

this const is to access all Lists:

```
const linkErrays = document.querySelectorAll('li');



const level = (section) => {
    return Math.floor(section.getBoundingClientRect().top)
}

const delateClass = (section) => {
    section.classList.remove('active_section');
}

const addClass = (condition, section) => {
    if (condition) {
        section.classList.add('active_section');
    }
}
```

this is the class activation when someone scroll

```
const classActivation = () => {

      linkErrays.forEach(section => {
        const elementLevel = level(section);

        inviewport = () => elementLevel < 50  && elementLevel >= -650

        delateClass(section);
    addClass(inviewport(), section);
  });
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', classActivation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a scroll event to the window and then either remove the class or toggle it.
i.e
`window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{ element.classList.remove('active'); })`

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I think selecting your `li` only once and before actually generating them may be what cause the issue, I would suggest generating them before like so:

```js
const navigation = document.getElementById('nav_list');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
// using map / join to avoid the navLinks variable
navigation.innerHTML = sections.map(section => {
    const sectId = section.id;
    const sectNav = section.dataset.name;
    return `<li><a class="links_menu" href="#${sectId}">${sectNav}</a></li>`;
}).join('\n');

// query the li after creation
const links = document.querySelectorAll('li')
```

tell me if this help.

edit: I completly missed that you re-query them after in the `linkErrays` variables, so my answer will not help with your current problem.